# Why does all Jest tests suites fail with "TypeError: (0 , _expect.setState) is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am using Remix.js plus typescript. A test-suite will run fine when I remove the `jest.config.js` file but error out with **"TypeError: (0 , _expect.setState) is not a function"**. I need my config file in order to run transforms on typescript tests. I will provide the test file and the file I am trying to test as well as all config setup. Not sure how to triage this issue myself. I find it out that a simple config seems to cause this issue.

### service.test.ts

```
import { fetch } from '@remix-run/node'

import { getGames, mapGamesData } from '../api/service'

const mockFetch = fetch as jest.MockedFn<typeof fetch>
const mockResponse = (mockData: any): Response =>
  ({ json: async () => mockData } as Response)

const mockGames = {
  data: [
    {
      id: 857429,
      date: '2022-10-28T00:00:00.000Z',
      home_team: {
        id: 18,
        abbreviation: 'MIN',
        city: 'Minnesota',
        conference: 'West',
        division: 'Northwest',
        full_name: 'Minnesota Timberwolves',
        name: 'Timberwolves',
      },
      home_team_score: 0,
      period: 0,
      postseason: false,
      season: 2022,
      status: '8:00 PM ET',
      time: '',
      visitor_team: {
        id: 14,
        abbreviation: 'LAL',
        city: 'Los Angeles',
        conference: 'West',
        division: 'Pacific',
        full_name: 'Los Angeles Lakers',
        name: 'Lakers',
      },
      visitor_team_score: 0,
    },
    {
      id: 857440,
      date: '2022-10-29T00:00:00.000Z',
      home_team: {
        id: 7,
        abbreviation: 'DAL',
        city: 'Dallas',
        conference: 'West',
        division: 'Southwest',
        full_name: 'Dallas Mavericks',
        name: 'Mavericks',
      },
      home_team_score: 0,
      period: 0,
      postseason: false,
      season: 2022,
      status: '9:00 PM ET',
      time: '',
      visitor_team: {
        id: 21,
        abbreviation: 'OKC',
        city: 'Oklahoma City',
        conference: 'West',
        division: 'Northwest',
        full_name: 'Oklahoma City Thunder',
        name: 'Thunder',
      },
      visitor_team_score: 0,
    },
  ],
  meta: {
    total_pages: 24,
    current_page: 1,
    next_page: 2,
    per_page: 50,
    total_count: 1161,
  },
}

jest.mock('@remix-run/node', () => ({
  fetch: mockFetch,
}))

describe.skip('getGames', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockFetch.mockClear()
  })

  it('should return list of games', async () => {
    // mockFetch.mockResolvedValue(mockResponse(mockGames))

    // const expectedResults = await getGames()

    // expect(expectedResults).toEqual(mapGamesData(mockGames.data))

    expect(true).toBeTruthy()
  })
})
```

### Jest Config

```
/** @type {import(@jest/types).Config.InitialOptions} */

module.exports = {
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '<rootDir>/src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    '!**/*.d.ts',
    '!**/entry.*.*',
    '!**/node_modules/**',
    '!**/root.*',
    '!**/routes/**',
    '!**/index.*',
  ],
  coverageDirectory: '<rootDir>/reports',

  coverageReporters: ['json', 'lcov', 'text'],

  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      branches: 80,
      functions: 80,
      lines: 50,
      statements: 50,
    },
  },

  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/node_modules'],

  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],

  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',

  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/'],

  transform: {
    // https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transform-objectstring-pathtotransformer--pathtotransformer-object
    '^.+\\.[jt]sx?$': [
      'babel-jest',
      {
        presets: [
          '@babel/preset-env',
          ['@babel/preset-react', { runtime: 'automatic' }],
          '@babel/preset-typescript',
        ],
        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'],
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

### Jest Setup file

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'

import { installGlobals } from '@remix-run/node'
import { configure } from '@testing-library/react'

configure({ testIdAttribute: 'data-test' })

installGlobals()
```

[Source Code](https://github.com/rekara-llc/Ball-Hog) - Dev Branch

### Error

[image: Jest Error]